# How to open specific post on Facebook android App?

Tags: android, json, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I'm getting the JSON news feed from a Facebook page using this web service:

```
https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format=json&id=20531316728
```

It will send a newsfeed object like this:

```
{
    title: " Take a look back on some of your most celebrated moments over the years.",
    id: "b6db41d28d5f1e96990c116d24f45cf1",
    alternate: "http://www.facebook.com/facebook/posts/959895899447",
    categories: [ ],
    published: "2014-02-05T08:00:00+00:00",
    updated: "2014-02-05T08:00:00+00:00",
    author: {
        name: "Facebook"
    },
    verb: "",
    target: "",
    objects: "",
    comments: "",
    likes: "",
    content: "Take a look back on some of your most celebrated moments over the years.<br/><br/><a href="http://www.facebook.com/lookback" id="" title="" target="" onclick="" style=""><img class="img" src="https://fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net/safe_image.php?d=AQBj1UxM999Q3X1f&amp;w=154&amp;h=154&amp;url=fbstaging%3A%2F%2Fgraph.facebook.com%2Fstaging_resources%2FMDExMDE1MjUxMzgxODI3MTcyOToxNjcyNTI2ODcy" alt="" /></a><br/><a href="http://www.facebook.com/lookback" id="" target="_blank" style="">A look back</a><br/>www.facebook.com/lookback<br/> "
},
```

What I want is open this specific post on Facebook Android app. Somewhere in StackOverflow I saw that this post can be opened by using following format in the Android intent:

```
fb://post/{postid}?owner={uid}
```

I tried both with fb and facebook in about format. But this is not opening the specific post on the Android app. Sometime this directs me to my newsfeed and sometimes shows no post error.

I just wanna know if there is any way to open specific page in Facebook Android app.

Comment: There is a lot of change going on almost every month in Facebook App, you can use value of "alternate" to show in webview. I guess it will help.